# Bootstrap Grid layout second row formating

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[Sample Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXmrS.png)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:aquamarine">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" style="background-color:burlywood">Label1:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:aquamarine">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" style="background-color:burlywood">Label2:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8"><input type="text" class="form-control"/></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:aquamarine">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" style="background-color:burlywood">Label3:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color:red">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" style="background-color:burlywood">Label4:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>            


    </div>
```

I have this bootstrap layout. I am having problem with aligning second row controls.

I want Label 4 align under Label 1. And then the rest of the width I want to use for text box (or list of check boxes, with three check box in a row)

I am not able figure it out how to do this. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide some code samples.

Comment: Just did. I am not sure why It did not add snippet before. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0;">
            <label class="col-md-1 control-label" style="background-color:burlywood">Label1:</label>
            <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0;">
            <label class="col-md-1 control-label" style="background-color:burlywood">Label2:</label>
            <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0;">
            <label class="col-md-1 control-label" style="background-color:burlywood">Label3:</label>
            <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label" style="background-color:burlywood">Label4:</label>
        <div class="col-md-11"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/oligustafsson/cpqor8kx/2/

Comment: I would like to align Label 4 under Label 1 and also the input-box for Label 4 to align under input-box for Label 1 and stretch all the way to label 3 Control

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I did, but it did not work for me. Your suggestion is placing the controls one after another vertically.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, you need to wrap them in 'container-fluid', sorry

Comment: Thanks. That helped.

Comment: @Oil, I am having a new problem. When I add 4th form group on first row, it is doing weird wrapping. I was expecting the forth group to move to second row and start from left side. Here is link to the sample code. http://www.bootply.com/jIM2JqIof3

Comment: @Emahum, you have (3 + 1) * 4 = 16 columns. Bootstrap default column space is only 12 on each row.